# Order Bars in interactive graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am creating an interactive graph using ggplot2 and plotly in R, the code is below.

I want to reorder the barchart column values so that they are sorted in descending order, 
currently they are sorted alphabetically.

Edit: I might not have made what I wanted clear. Currently, the midfielder with the most points is Salah, but the top row in my midfielder column is currently Alli. I would like to sort the column so that the values are in descending order of points rather than alphabetical.

Would someone please inform me how I can do this?

I have saved the finished graph & csv file at the below locations:

IG: https://ianfm94.github.io/Premier_League_Stats/Top_100_Fantasy_PL_Pointscorers.html

CSV File: https://github.com/Ianfm94/Premier_League_Stats/blob/master/CSV_Files/2020-06-01_updated_fpl_stats.csv

```
rm(list=ls())

# Required packages, you might need to install these
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)

## Fantasy_PL Data 

fpl_data = read.csv('2020-06-01_updated_fpl_stats.csv',
                header = T, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
attach(fpl_data)
#View(fpl_data)

# Interactive Plot Workings

top_100_points = total_points[0:100]
top_100_player_pos = factor(player_pos)[0:100]
top_100_surnames = factor(web_name)[0:100]
top_100_team = factor(team_name)[0:100]

color_table = tibble(
  Team_Name = c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Bournemouth", "Brighton & Hove Albion",
                "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", 
                "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester City",
                "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", "Norwich City",
                "Sheffield United", "Southampton", "Tottenham Hotspurs",
                "Watford", "West Ham United", "Wolverhampton Wanderers"),
  Team_Color = c("#EF0107", "#670E36", "#B50E12", "#0057B8",
                 "#6C1D45", "#034694", "#1B458F", "#003399",
                 "#003090", "#C8102E", "#6CABDD", "#DA291C",
                 "#241F20", "#FFF200", "#EE2737", "#D71920",
                 "#132257", "#FBEE23", "#7A263A", "#FDB913")
)

position_table = tibble(
  Position_Name = c("Goalkeeper", "Defender", "Midfielder", "Striker"),
)

fpl_df = data.frame(y = top_100_points, 
                    x = top_100_player_pos, 
                    z = top_100_surnames,
                    w = top_100_team,
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

fpl_df$w = factor(fpl_df$w, levels = color_table$Team_Name)
fpl_df$x = factor(fpl_df$x, levels = position_table$Position_Name)

names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "x"] = "Position_Name"
names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "y"] = "Total_Points_by_Position"
names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "z"] = "Player_Surname"
names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "w"] = "Team_Name"
#View(fpl_df)

plot_fpl_1 = ggplot(fpl_df, aes(x = Position_Name,
                                y = Total_Points_by_Position,
                                z = Player_Surname,
                                fill = Team_Name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_table$Team_Color) + 
  labs(title = "Top 100 Fantasy PL Pointscorer by Position & Team",
       y = "Total Points of Position",
       x = "Player Positions",
       fill = "Team Name") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_text(color = "navy",
                                    face = "bold",
                                    size = 10))  
plot_fpl_1 = ggplotly(plot_fpl_1)
plot_fpl_1
```

Comment: The idea is to sort your df descending, use index as x and then overwrite xticks using player positions.

Comment: I think what I wrote might not have been clear, I've manually set the order of the columns correctly already, as in I want them to be in the current order "Goalie, Defender, etc". What I'm looking for is the values within each column to be sorted from highest points to lowest points, i.e. to have Salah as the highest midfielder then De Bruyne, rather than the way it is currently with Alli, then Almiron. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_reorder` to change the order of `z`. See below:

***Libraries:***

```r
# Required packages, you might need to install these
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)
library(RCurl)
library(forcats)
```

***Data:***

```
## Fantasy_PL Data 
csvurl <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ianfm94/Premier_League_Stats/master/CSV_Files/2020-06-01_updated_fpl_stats.csv")
fpl_data  <- read.csv(text = csvurl)
attach(fpl_data)

# Interactive Plot Workings
top_100_points = total_points[0:100]
top_100_player_pos = factor(player_pos)[0:100]
top_100_surnames = factor(web_name)[0:100]
top_100_team = factor(team_name)[0:100]

color_table = tibble(
  Team_Name = c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Bournemouth", "Brighton & Hove Albion",
                "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", 
                "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester City",
                "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", "Norwich City",
                "Sheffield United", "Southampton", "Tottenham Hotspurs",
                "Watford", "West Ham United", "Wolverhampton Wanderers"),
  Team_Color = c("#EF0107", "#670E36", "#B50E12", "#0057B8",
                 "#6C1D45", "#034694", "#1B458F", "#003399",
                 "#003090", "#C8102E", "#6CABDD", "#DA291C",
                 "#241F20", "#FFF200", "#EE2737", "#D71920",
                 "#132257", "#FBEE23", "#7A263A", "#FDB913")
)

position_table = tibble(
  Position_Name = c("Goalkeeper", "Defender", "Midfielder", "Striker"),
)

fpl_df = data.frame(y = top_100_points, 
                    x = top_100_player_pos, 
                    z = top_100_surnames,
                    w = top_100_team,
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

fpl_df$w = factor(fpl_df$w, levels = color_table$Team_Name)
fpl_df$x = factor(fpl_df$x, levels = position_table$Position_Name)

names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "x"] = "Position_Name"
names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "y"] = "Total_Points_by_Position"
names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "z"] = "Player_Surname"
names(fpl_df)[names(fpl_df) == "w"] = "Team_Name"
```

***Plot:***

```
plot_fpl_1 = ggplot(fpl_df, aes(x = Position_Name,
                                y = Total_Points_by_Position,
                                z = fct_reorder(Player_Surname, -Total_Points_by_Position),
                                fill = Team_Name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_table$Team_Color) + 
  labs(title = "Top 100 Fantasy PL Pointscorer by Position & Team",
       y = "Total Points of Position",
       x = "Player Positions",
       fill = "Team Name") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_text(color = "navy",
                                    face = "bold",
                                    size = 10))  

plot_fpl_2 = ggplotly(plot_fpl_1)
plot_fpl_2
```

[image]

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it too, thanks very much! Not all heroes wear capes, some are great at R.

Comment: @IanMurray you're welcome; I prefer I had a cape tho ;)